# Set 100% height and width of fabric js canvas

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I want to set the height and width of canvas according to the background image.

For example, if the height and width of the image are less than screen size then canvas size is 100% of the screen and if image size is greater than screen size then canvas adjusts according to it without cutting image and show scrollbars.

Currently, I have fix the height and width of the canvas

```
 <canvas id="canvas" width="720" height="800"></canvas>
```

and background image code is

```
 canvas.setBackgroundImage('./img/form.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {      
    });
```

How to make canvas height and width dynamic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make canvas as wide and as high as parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214873/make-canvas-as-wide-and-as-high-as-parent)

Comment: I want to set canvas according to background image not parent

Answer (score 0):

I have set dynamic canvas size using

```
    var image = new Image()
    image.src = './img/form.jpg';
    image.onload = function () {
        var canv = $('#canvas');
        canv.attr('width', image.width);
        canv.attr('height', image.height);
        canvas.dispose();
        setTimeout(() => {
            canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
            canvas.setBackgroundImage('./img/form.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {});
        }, 500);

    };
```